# Python, import command works in spyder but not in the console

Tags: python, spyder

The command `from scipy import spatial` works perfectly in Spyder. But when I directly start the python.exe which is used in Spyder and type `from scipy import spatial` in the console, I get an error ("DLL load failed..."). I don't understand how it can be. It is the same python.exe program in both cases. Could anyone please help me.

I use Windows 7. The background of my question: I want to run my program via task scheduler in Windows. The program runs fine via Spyder. But not in the task scheduler. The reason is described above.

Comment: I suspect your using Windows OS. Please specify your system-setting

Comment: check `python -V` to see if you really use the same Python.